# String removal in R

Tags: r, string

Previously, I asked the question

[Generating DNA codon combinations in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61396134/generating-dna-codon-combinations-in-r/61396839#61396839)

of which I am now trying to implement a faster version, but am experiencing an unexpected issue.

**My attempt**

```
library(ape)

codon.tbl <- "vertebrate mitochondrial"

pos1 <- c("a", "c", "g", "t")
pos2 <- c("a", "c", "g", "t")
pos3 <- c("a", "c", "g", "t")

codons <- expand.grid(pos1, pos2, pos3)
codons <- paste0(codons$Var1, codons$Var2, codons$Var3)

# Exclude stop codons

if (codon.tbl == "standard") {
  stop.codons <- c("taa", "tag", "tga")
} else if (codon.tbl == "vertebrate mitochondrial") {
  stop.codons <- c("aga", "agg", "taa", "tag")
} else {
  # invertebrate mitochondrial
  stop.codons <- c("taa", "tag")
}

codons <- codons[which(codons != stop.codons)] # problematic line
```

The line of code immediately above should contain only 60 elements since when codon.tbl == "vertebrate mitochondrial", there are 4 possible stop codons; instead, 'codons' contains 62 elements.

When I run the code, 'codons' still contains the strings "agg" and "taa"; only "aga" and "tag" have been removed.

I am not sure why this is occurring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `%in%` and negate (`!`) instead of `!=` because the 'stop.codons' `length` is greater than 1 and `==` or `!=` works as elementwise comparison

```
out <- codons[!codons %in% stop.codons] 
any(c('agg', 'taa') %in% out)
#[1] FALSE
```

---

As a simple example

```
v1 <- 1:5
v2 <- 2:3
v1 == v2
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

here, the first element of 'v1' i.e. 1 is compared with 2, next with 3, and then the 3rd element of 'v1' i.e. 3 with 2 (recycling of the shorter vector).

While, using `%in%`, it check for the entire `vector` whether the element is present

```
v1 %in% v2
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Or with `setdiff` if there are no duplicates

```
setdiff(codons, stop.codons)
```

Or use `vsetdiff` from `vecsets`

```
library(vecsets)
vsetdiff(codons, stop.codons)
```